# Delphi XE7,Unicode display problems with PageProducer on WebBroker

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe7

I'm writing a multilanguage WebBroker application (for Apache 2.2) which display unicode encoded data from an oracle database. The same data with the same data-aware components (Devart's ODAC) in a test program written in Delphi XE7, are displaying correctly.
My problem occured in the WebBroker where I'm facing with a strange behavior when I'm using a PageProducer to prepare the content for the response
When I'm using the follow code in the action :

```
Response.ContentType := 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
PageProducer1.HTMLFile:= htmltemplate
Response.Content := 
  PageProducer1.Content+
  'Label 1 ='+Label1fromDB+
  ' Label 2='+Label2fromDB+
  '</body></html>';
Response.SendResponse;
```

the result in the webbrowser is that all the non-latin chars that was not inserted by the PageProducer but already existed in the htmltemplate file (which has declared as utf-8 with ) replaced by other not correct chars, the text that was inserted by the PageProducer and was retrived from the database also not displayed correctly but the extra labels, Label1fromDB and Label2fromDB which are added to the content response as showing in the code above are displayed correctly having also the same chars which are inside the htmltemplate.

Now, when I omit the declaration

```
Response.ContentType := 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

the content of the htmltemplate are diplaying correctly but all the other texts , the text filled by PageProducer and the two labels Label1fromDB and Label2fromDB not correctly

Can you please help me identify where the problem is and what have I do in order to be able to serve unicode multilanguage content via web broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues with different Unicode encodings.

Both `PageProducer.Content` and `Response.Content` are `UTF16` encoded strings. Your `htmltemplate` is encoded in `UTF8` and is not correctly interpreted by `PageProducer`.

Most likely cause is that `htmltemplate` file does not have `UTF8 BOM` at beginning and `PageProducer` will interpret that file encoding as default `ANSI`. If that is so, adding `UTF8 BOM` should solve your problem.

Comment: Many many thanks for your clarifications Dalija, the problem solved, it was exacly this omited BOM at beginning of the html. So I produced an new html file with the BOM and the PageProducer encoded correctly.